# How to store a PHP variable in a HTML attribute?

Tags: php, html, colors, echo

I want to create a page which allows a user to select colours (among the listed ones, via checkboxes). When the user clicks on the submit button, all the selected colours should get displayed with their corresponding colours as their font colour.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['button'])) { 
?>
    Colours<br>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method=post>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="Red">Red<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="Blue">Blue<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="Green">Green<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="Yellow">Yellow<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" value="Pink">Pink<br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Show"> </form>
    <?php
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['colours'])) {
        echo "Colours selected are:<br><UL type=circle>";
        foreach($_POST['colours'] as $color) 
            echo "<LI><font color='echo $color'; >$color</font>";
        echo"</UL>";
    } else { 
        echo "No colour selected"; 
    }
} 
?>
```

There is a bug somewhere, the font colors are not as expected.
I want it like this image below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Many errrors. 1) complete form tag 2)Write echo " <li> <font color= '$color'; >  $color </font>";

Comment: I suggest you clear doubts on HTML first.http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: @Ravi-Hirani There was only one error, and now resolved..

Comment: @Amit-Ray What do you mean? I know HTML, and the HTML code is correct.

Comment: @RisingUnderDog Whether it should be method=post or method="post" ?

Comment: @RisingUnderDog: You haven't completed </li> tag also.

Comment: HTML <font> Tag. Not Supported in HTML5. Reference: [Font Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)

Comment: @AmitRay What I know is method=post, method='post' and method="post" all three are correct, am I wrong?

Comment: @RaviHirani It is not mandatory to close <li> tag, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550788/does-the-li-tag-in-html-have-an-ending-tag

Comment: @RisingUnderDog You can never be wrong because you read and understand everything partially. Read this again for li tag "An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element." Is the last li element followed by another li element in the loop. Also can you show me an example in stackoverflow where method=post is used.

Comment: @AmitRay Well that was an elucidative example. Do it for yourself <li> needs not to be closed, it's a kinda empty tag. And regarding method=post issue, it wasn't a complex code so I didn't use either of them ("" or ''), most of the times I use single codes but here it wasn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appending a string to variable or another string, you must concatenate the values with a . (dot). for example:

```
echo("<li><font color=".$color.">".$color."</font>");
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved, but I wanna ask why putting dots solved the problem?

Comment: in php for appending one string to other u must use dots

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @EatMyDust Oh, I read about this but I didn't understand it's use, now it's absolutely clear. Thanks again.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ Is your comment somehow related to me? I can't understand your comment.. :P

Comment: @RisingUnderDog Nah Nah. The comment was for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply write

```
echo "<li><font color='$color'> $color </font></li>"; // complete li tag
```

other mistakes:-

a) form method attrubute should be **method='post'**

b) UL type=circle should be **ul type='circle'**

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
  echo "Colours selected are:<br><UL type=circle>";
  foreach($_POST['colours'] as $color) {
    echo " <LI><font color='".$color."'>'".$color."'</font></LI>";
  }
  echo"</UL>";
```

Comment: type='circle' or type=circle?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!