# PHP DomDocument results empty <li> tag without closing tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a html code that contains:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

after parsing it using php `DOMDocument` and using `saveHTML` function of it, the result is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
</ul>
```

this only happens with `<li>` tags. how to force the output to include closing tag for `<li>` tags?

I tried to solve with regex but couldn't find a solution. If you have a regex solution I accept it too.

Comment: Why? The end tag for `<li>` elements is optional.

Comment: @Quentin I know but prefer to have the end tag. without it looks buggy to me.

Comment: The behavior appears to be dependent on having content or not with another `li` element proceeding it.

Comment: @Scuzzy This is ***not*** a duplicate.  That question is about HTML.  This question is about PHP's implementation of DOMDocument.  (Shoes are not a duplicate of socks, even though they are both worn on the feet.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not a duplicate see above.

Comment: @Jake `An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.` Also, this was closed October of 2017

Comment: Creating a text node with an empty string inside the `<li>` seems sufficient for PHP to output the closing tag.  PHP seems to overlook the fact that whitespace *between* the `<li>`s could affect the rendering and omits the closing tag despite this.

Comment: @Scuzzy That does not answer ***this*** question and when this was actually closed is irrelevant.

Comment: PHP DOMDocument is producing valid HTML, to get the required output post processing is required.

Comment: this adds empty tags:
`$nodes = $DOMXPath->query('/html/body//*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]');
foreach($nodes as $nodes__value) { $nodes__value->nodeValue = ''; } $DOMDocument->saveHTML();`

Comment: or even:
`$nodes = $DOMXPath->query('/html/body//*[not(node())]');
foreach($nodes as $nodes__value) { $nodes__value->nodeValue = ''; } $DOMDocument->saveHTML();`

Answer (score -2):

As per [Does the <li> tag in HTML have an ending tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550788/does-the-li-tag-in-html-have-an-ending-tag)

> An `li` element's end tag may be omitted if the `li` element is immediately followed by another `li` element or if there is no more content in the parent element.

```
$html = '
<html>
  <body>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Prints

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
  <ul><li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>
    <li>
    </ul></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know it is optional. Buy my prefer is to have it.