# Nuxt generate not closing tags

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, static-site

I'm having some trouble with nuxt generate, the output file generated isn't closing tags correctly,

The earliest tag in the document that's not closing is an li tag. Here's an example of my component and how it appears in the generated output file,

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="sec-nav-container row">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="sec-nav">
        <li class="sec-nav-item">Manage Connections</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

dist

```
<div class="sec-nav-container row" data-v-55f11ed2>
    <div class="container" data-v-55f11ed2>
          <ul class="sec-nav" data-v-55f11ed2>
                <li class="sec-nav-item" data-v-55f11ed2>Manage Connections</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML produced by nuxt is minified. And since closing [li is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550788/does-the-li-tag-in-html-have-an-ending-tag#20550925), it's stripped.