# php DOMDocument saveHTML missing close tag for empty tag li

Tags: php, document

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<ul><li>123</li><li></li></ul>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NOERROR);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

I expect to see  `<ul><li>123</li><li></li></ul>` instead of `<ul><li>123</li><li></ul>`, anyone can help me ?

Comment: You should use flag `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`

Comment: Could be because [Does the `<li>` tag in HTML have an ending tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550788/does-the-li-tag-in-html-have-an-ending-tag)

Comment: @Mohammad not xml, it's saveHtml. I tried `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` and got the same result.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you. [Option-Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#optional-tags). An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.

Comment: this adds empty tags:
`$nodes = $DOMXPath->query('/html/body//*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]');
foreach($nodes as $nodes__value) { $nodes__value->nodeValue = ''; } $DOMDocument->saveHTML();`

Comment: or even:
`$nodes = $DOMXPath->query('/html/body//*[not(node())]');
foreach($nodes as $nodes__value) { $nodes__value->nodeValue = ''; } $DOMDocument->saveHTML();`

Answer (score 0):

End tag is optional, [Option-Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#optional-tags). An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.